# Is it good to change type over __getitem__ method overloading?

Tags: python, oop

I have a class `myclass` which is at core a list `data` which represent times + the methods facilities to deal with that list. I'd like to be able to support numpy-style operations over `data`.

So I thought about overloading the `__getitem__` operator as follow:

```
def __getitem__(self,i):
    import numpy as np
    return np.array(self.data)[i]
```

This for example makes very easy to deal with a change of the `data` zero time to the first element via:

```
x = myclass()
print(x[:] - x[0])
```

Still it looks shady to me.

I'm wondering: is this a decent enough practice?
New to OOP and OOP design.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **new** to make your class as np.array.

```py
import numpy as np
class MyClass:
    def __new__(cls, data):
        return np.array(data)


x = MyClass([1, 2, 3, 4])
print(x[:])
print(x[0])
print(x[:] - x[0])
```

It will be

```
[1 2 3 4]
1
[0 1 2 3]
```